# How to automatically save received pdf files from gmail into a database?

Tags: database, gmail-api, email-attachments

I would like to know if this scenario would be possible in any programming language combined with any database technology.

I would like to automatically save received pdf files that are attached in emails into a database. Is this possible? Is there any library or framework available to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would recommend using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) for this. The approach you should follow is to use the `GmailApp` class  ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)) to get the messages you need, you can use methods like `getInboxThreads()` ([Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getinboxthreads)), to retrieve the messages.

After you've found the message and retrieved the attachment (which you can do with`getAttachments()` ([Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getattachments))), you can use the [JDBC Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) to connect with external databases. The specifics here depend a lot on what database you want to connect with, but the documentation will lead you in the right direction.